# String filtering in r using gsub

Tags: r, string, gsub

Consider the vector

```
v<-  'I l@ove d**^%ata 33-99//""(Sci"ence==+)'
```

I want to clean it using `gsub` in R as

```
"I Love Data Science"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We match one or more characters that are not an alphabet or space and replace it with `''`.  The `[[:alpha:]]+` by itself matches one or more alphabetic characters.  But, suppose we need to do the reverse of that i.e. match one or more character that are not alphabet, use `[^[:alpha:]]+`, i.e. `^` inside the first `[` negates the match.  Here we also need the white spaces.  Without it, we get `"IlovedataScience"`.  So, use that also in the match i.e. `[^[:alpha:] ]+`.

```
gsub("[^[:alpha:] ]+", "", v1)
#[1] "I love data Science"
```

Or use `[[:punct:]]` to match any punctuation characters and replace with `''`

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]+|[0-9]+", '', v1)
```

Or instead of `[[:alpha:]]`, we can specify the alphabets as `[A-Za-z]` (as @alistaire commented)

```
gsub('[^A-Za-z ]', '', v1)
```

#### Update

If the OP wants to have starting letter for each word as upper case,

```
gsub("\\b(.)", "\\U\\1", gsub('[^A-Za-z ]', '', v1), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "I Love Data Science"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 'I l@ove d**^%ata 33-99//""(Sci"ence==+)'
```

Comment: An equivalent I was going to post: `gsub('[^A-Za-z ]', '', v1)`

Comment: This is a blanket solution which _may_ work for the OP, but could easily break should the needs change.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I take back the comment as you changed the solution.

Comment: can you explain me the full command in detail

Comment: @MilanAmrutJoshi  Sure, I will add more description

Comment: @RHertel  Thanks, didn't notice that.  Corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option which explicitly replaces *only* the special characters which appear in your input vector:

```
chars <- c("@", "*", "^", "%", "/", "\"", "=", "+", "d", "(", ")", "-")
gsub(paste("\\", chars, sep="", collapse="|"), "", statement)
[1] "I love data Science"
```

Note that I escape every character in `chars` with `\\` in case it be an R regex metacharacter (and in the event that it is not, no harm is done).

The answer given by @akrun is cleaner and is the way to go if a broad character class covers what you want to replace.  I hope that this answer will be useful to someone who has the need to replace a set of individual characters which don't neatly fit into a class.